# Python - Scrapy / can find a Xpath query with @class but not with @id

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I´m trying to learn Scrapy for Python with the following guide : http://brutalsimplicity.github.io/2016/07/25/scrapy.html . I have followed the instructions and i am able to manually scrape some data via the scrapy shell, but i have problems targeting what i want. When i try to target the following div class :

```
<div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_pbp">
```

with @class:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="overthrow table_container"]')
```

then it works and i get

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="overthrow table_container"]' data=u'<div class="overthrow table_container" i'>]
```

as a response, but when i try to do the same with @id:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="div_pbp"]')
```

i get empty brackets [] as a response .

Edit1 : Im using windows 10, Python version 2.7.13 , Scrapy version 1.4.0
Am i formulating my queries wrongly or is there some other explenation?

Edit2 : I noticed that my output on the scrapy shell is cut off. When viewing all divs with //div i get the following output : 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vrNA.png)
Could this be the problem ? How can you tell scrapy to get the whole selector and not cut it off?

Edit3 : another Example :
When using the Dev Tools on the website, i see the selector should be :
`<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=u'<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper columns'>`

When i access it with :

`response.xpath('//div[@id="all_game_info"]')`

then i get :

`[<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=u'<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wra'>]`

so it cutt off a part. When i now try to search with the class variable like this

`response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wra"]')`

or

`response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wrapper columns"]')`

, then i get empty brackets []

Btw : this was all in the Scrapy shell

Comment: Whenever you supply code, such as the HTML in this question, would you please give it to us as text, inside your question, rather than as an image, so that anyone that wants to try out various possibilities can do so.

Comment: added it as text now

Comment: Both XPaths yield the same result for me. Can you edit your question and add some information about your environement (version, os)? I tested with python 2.7.11 and scrapy 1.4.0

Comment: If you want to reply to someone on SO you need to use '@'. For instance, to reply to me, use @BillBell.

Comment: Your xpaths produce the same results for me too. Must be 'something else', most probably in another part of your code.

Comment: @BillBell Thanks for the tipp! The problem is im running this from the scrapy shell, so i dont have any code before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got down to brass tacks and replicated the problem you face. I use neither the Scrapy shell nor IPython so you this will appear slightly different.

I get the content of the page using the `requests` library then use the `scrapy` `HtmlResponse` object to give myself the ability to search the page using xpath expressions.

My experience was the same as yours.

```
>>> url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201409040sea.htm'
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> response = HtmlResponse(url,body=page)
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="overthrow table_container"]')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="overthrow table_container"]' data='<div class="overthrow table_container" i'>]
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="div_pbp"]')
[]
```

So I looked at the HTML for `div_pbp`. I should **not** have been surprised: this happens so often. What we were looking for is in a comment, and there's only one of them in the page.

[image: in a comment]

EDIT: If the output from a statement will be textual and voluminous then one tactic you can use is to save that output to a Python name and then write that name to a file for examination. Something like this:

```
enormousOutput = <statement>
open('temp.txt', 'w').write(enormousOutput)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have a suggestion regarding the other question(cut off slectors) i asked in the Edit section ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! Sadly the output is still cutt off ( literally : the second part is not in the selector, not just not in one line). Any suggestions, or should i open another question for that problem? Thanks again! You are a great help!

Comment: It might be better if you do. Nice, clear, fresh start. If you wish, let me know when you've submitted the question.